# 'function' object is not subscriptable getting error

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVm5U.png)

click above for dataset

I am trying to remove ' min' from watch time and make it integer, but i am getting below error.

both split and regexp_replace are giving error

function' object is not subscriptable

below is the  code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = df.withColumn("Year Of Release",abs(col("Year of Release")))
df2= df1.withColumn("s", regexp_replace(col['Watch Time'],'f',' min')).show()
#df2 = df1.withColumn("Duration", split(col['Watch Time']," ").getItem(0))
df1.show()
```

Comment: df2= df1.withColumn("s", regexp_replace(df1['Watch Time'],' min','')).show()

this worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly import abs() from the pyspark module, otherwise it uses the builtin python function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, abs as pyspark_abs, regexp_replace

df1 = df.withColumn("Year Of Release", pyspark_abs(col("Year of Release")))
df2 = df1.withColumn("s", regexp_replace(col['Watch Time'], 'f', ' min')).show()
# df2 = df1.withColumn("Duration", split(col['Watch Time']," ").getItem(0))
df1.show()
```